# SpriteCollide Only Running Once Per Collision

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm checking `missileGroup` to see if any instances of `missile` collided with any instances `enemy` in `enemyGroup`. When run, it prints "Hit" for the first loop, but it ignores the second for loop. Why is that?

```
 #### Imagine this is in a game loop ####
        for missile in missileGroup:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(missile, enemyGroup, False) :
                print("Hit")

        
        for enemy in enemyGroup:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, missileGroup, False) == True:
                print("HI")
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) doesn't return `True` or `False`, but it return a list containing all *Sprites* in a *Group* that intersect with another *Sprite*. You have to evaluate whether the list is not empty instead of comparing the result with `True`:

<s>`if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, missileGroup, False) == True:`</s>

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, missileGroup, False):
```

---

Anyway use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) to find all sprites that collide between two groups.

```py
if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(missileGroup, enemyGroup, False, False):
    print("Hit")
```

---

See [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide):

> Return a list containing all Sprites in a Group that intersect with another Sprite.

See [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide)

> This will find collisions between all the Sprites in two groups.

Therefore the arguments to `spritecollide()` must be a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object and a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) object. the arguments to `groupcollide()` must be two `pygame.sprite.Group` objects.
A list of `pygame.sprite.Sprite` objects instead of the *Group* does not work.

```py
missileGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemyGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Furthermore read about [`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill)

> The Sprite is removed from **all** the Groups that contain it.

Hence if you call `kill()` in the 1st loop, the 2nd loop won't work, because the sprite is removed from **all** Groups.

You call `kill()` in the `reset` methods. `missile.reset()` respectively `eachEnemy.reset()` causes the 2nd loop to fail.

Comment: It still does not print anything in the console

Comment: @DaeshaunMorrison So there is another bug in your code, somewhere else.